# JavaScript mobile redirect possibilities

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

Can someone offer some clues as to why some of the following redirect codes work, and some do not?

The website is: www.themissingexperience.com/index.html

I'm only reporting on my user experience on an iPhone.

The following two redirect codes Do work:

1)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (screen.width <= 1023) {
    document.location = "http://m.themissingexperience.com";
}
</script>
```

2)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ( (screen.width < 1024) && (screen.height < 768) ) { 
window.location = 'http://m.themissingexperience.com/';
} 

</script>
```

But, this redirect code does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ($(window).width() <= 1023) {
window.location.assign("http://m.themissingexperience.com/")
}
</script>
```

However, this last script will work when I also have this line before the redirect code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
```

Why is that?

Thanks in advance.
I'm very much a novice.

Comment: Do you understand what **EVERY** character in that piece of code does?

Comment: The dollar sign in the second to last chunk of code you posted indicates that a jQuery function is being called. That jQuery function isn't in scope (and thus can't be called) unless jQuery is loaded before it's called. The last line of code you posted loads the jQuery library. Therefore the last line needs to go before the second to last line in order for the jQuery function to be in scope when it's called.

Answer (score 0):

`$(window).width()` uses jQuery. You need jQuery loaded before using it.